# Liouville—von Neumann Operator as a member of a Tensor space ( in an Open Quantum System )

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors, quantum-mechanics, quantum-groups

$\textbf{Context:}$

I'm posting in Math SE instead of Physics SE because this is really a question about differential geometry and vector spaces.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert Space, then $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ is a vector that describes a quantum mechanical state. Let $H$ be an operator such that $H |\psi \rangle = i \hbar \partial_t |\psi \rangle$.  In physics, when there is dissipation it is often useful to switch to a density matrix instead of a wavefunction representation.

$\rho = \sum_i P_i |\psi\rangle_i\langle\psi|_i$ where $P_i$ is the classical probability to find the $i$th state, and $\sum_i P_i = 1$. We'll restrict ourselves to a pure state - this doesn't matter for my question but it cleans up notation, so now $\rho = |\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$. Clearly, $\rho \in \mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H^*}$ because it will act left on a vector, and right on a covector to return a complex number. We can find the time evolution as follows:

$\partial_t\rho = \partial_t(|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|) = (\partial_t|\psi\rangle ) \langle\psi|+|\psi\rangle ( \partial_t \langle\psi|)= \frac{1}{i \hbar} H |\psi\rangle \langle\psi|+|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|\frac{1}{-i \hbar} H  = \frac{1}{i \hbar}[H,\rho]$

where $[A,B] = A B - B A$ is defined as the commutator.

$\textbf{Question:}$

Often times, we will define the Liouville Operator as follows:

$ \hat{\mathcal{L}} \rho=\frac{1}{i \hbar}[H,\rho]$, $ \hat{\mathcal{L}} = \frac{1}{i \hbar}[H,\cdot]$, or equivalently as the time derivative operator.

So this operator takes a (1,1) tensor, $\rho$, and gives us back a new (1,1) tensor.  $\textbf{Does that mean $\hat{\mathcal{L}}$ could be understood as a (2,2) tensor?}$ It does not seem like it is also a (1,1) tensor in $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H^*}$. $\textbf{Is it another object entirely that can't be understood with just a vector space structure?}$

Comment: I may have figured it out.  If we consider the tangent space formed by $\mathcal{L} = \partial_t$ acting on $\rho$ then it becomes clear that $\mathcal{L}$ will be a (2,2) tensor.